# Outlier detection packages in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am searching for R package which provide the possibility to detect outlier(s) in some sample of observations?

Thanks alot.

Shahzad

Comment: Well, there is a package called `outliers`...

Comment: Your question is very broad and general. SO deals with specific programming questions, preferably with a reproducible example.

Comment: I have used outliers package but do it detects more than 1 outliers. Because when I used it, it was detecting only 1 outlier. I know its vague but may be I wasn't doing it right.

Comment: Go to this pdf and read the discussion on finding outliers, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Zhao_R_and_data_mining.pdf very useful.

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `r outlier detection` gives a number of interesting results, e.g. the `outliers` or `extremevalues` packages.